# Is it good practice to curry a React hook to follow DRY?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, standards, currying

React hooks need to be invoked inside a React component or a custom React hook. It cannot be used inside a loop. With that in mind, consider the following situation:

```
const useListenToStateChange = (state, onEvent, key) => {
    const value = state[key];
    useEffect(() => {
        if (value === null) {
            onEvent(null);
        } else {
            onEvent(key, value);
        }
    }, [value]);
};

const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
    const { context, onError } = props;
    const { state } = useContext(context);
    
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[0]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[1]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[2]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[3]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[4]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[5]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[6]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[7]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[8]);
    useListenToStateChange(state, onError, KEY_ARRAY[9]);
    
    return <Text>{getTitle(state)}</Text>;
};
```

The return value of `ExampleComponent` is not really the point, so feel free to ignore it. My concern is that `useListenToStateChange` is copy-pasted ten times, obviously violating the DRY principle.

Assume we need to call `useListenToStateChange` in this way -- we need a listener to the values of the `state` object returned by `useContext`, which executes a function with side-effects when a change happens (ie, the callback cannot be invoked inside the reducer that updates `state`; we need to call `useEffect`).

Here is where currying comes to the rescue (note: I use `curry` and `map` from `lodash/fp`):

```
const useListenToStateChange = _.curry((state, onEvent, key) => {
    const value = state[key];
    useEffect(() => {
        if (value === null) {
            onEvent(null);
        } else {
            onEvent(key, value);
        }
    }, [value]);
});

const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
    const { context, onError } = props;
    const { state } = useContext(context);
    
    const listenToState = useListenToStateChange(state, onError);
    _.map(listenToState, KEY_ARRAY);
    
    return <Text>{getTitle(state)}</Text>;
};
```

The above code is valid in React Native and runs without throwing an error.

I like how it reads, and I like that this method enables us to avoid copy-pasting all the keys. Imagine if you had several listeners you needed to set up based on the `KEY_ARRAY` array. That would be a nightmare. At a glance, we're also following the rule of hooks this way: `useListenToStateChange` is a hook that returns a JavaScript function, and we invoke the hook inside a React component.

But the "problem" I'm pondering is, when you curry a function, obviously it doesn't execute yet. You must provide the last argument for it to run. This means `listenToState` is technically a React hook: when you call it, it will execute the `useEffect` hook inside `useListenToStateChange`.

However, it isn't named like a hook and thus skirts the checking in React that says you must call it at the top level. This means you can map over `KEY_ARRAY`, and since it's a predefined, non-dynamic array, the hooks are guaranteed to be called in the same sequence with every render. Thus, it avoids the problem outlined in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation).

So my question is: does this use of currying a React hook violate the rules of hooks? In other words, is this pattern good practice?

Answer (score 0):

> does this use of currying a React hook violate the rules of hooks?

No. It's okay to use currying.

> is this pattern good practice?

It looks okay to me.

However, I would not suggest to use state from outside. You can just make use of state inside that function:

```
const useListenToStateChange = (onEvent, key) => {
  const { state } = useContext(YourContext);
```